# Кнопка «читать далее»

Tags: php, wordpress

Сейчас на [сайте](https://apple-master.ru/blog/) статью обрывает `[…]`. Как можно увеличить количество слов до обрыва и поменять многоточие на надпись «читать далее». Вставить разрыв статьи через редактор не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря как в коде выводятся записи. Если через `the_excerpt();` то увеличить количество выводимых слов можно добавив в `functions.php` такой код:

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', function(){
    return 20;
} );
```

Цифру 20 - заменить на нужное.

Заменить точки на конце можно таким кодом:

```
add_filter('excerpt_more', function($more) {
    return '...';
});
```

Опять же - вместо трех точек вписать нужное.

Я предпочитаю использовать `wp_trim_words()` вместо `the_excerpt()`. В случае с ним это делается в шаблоне вывода статей. Количество слов и символы в конце передаются как аргументы функции:

```
<?=wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 5, ' ...' );?>
```

Answer (score 1):

*YouThemeName/functions.php...*

**add new code... >**

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
function new_excerpt_more( $more ){
    global $post;
    return '<a href="'. get_permalink($post) . '">читать далее...</a>';
}
```